# Add the contents of an array to a combo box

Tags: java, netbeans

I have an array (in another class) with 10 values in.
I want to add the values of this array into a combo box.
Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: See also, http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
Object[] yourArray = otherClass.getMyArray();
JComboBox box = new JComboBox (yourArray);
```

This will call `Object.toString()` to get the value to display in the combo box, so if you are using a custom class make sure it overrides the `toString()` method.

EDIT:

There are a few ways to do this in Netbeans.  Here's one way.  Somewhere in your form, have a method like this:

```
private ComboBoxModel getComboModel (OtherClass myOtherClass)
{
  return new DefaultComboBoxModel (myOtherClass.getMyArray());
}
```

And then in the form designer:

1. click on the combo box
2. edit the Model propert in the properties editor
3. select **Value from existing component** in the drop down
4. select the **Method call** radio button and choose `getComboModel()`

There are many other ways to do it, but this will work for a simple case like yours.  In general, if you want to make it Netbeans friendly, then you need to provide a method somewhere that returns an instance of ComboBoxModel and point Netbeans at it.

Comment: Hm, where ever it needs to go.  By the way, you're not coding in NetBeans are you?

Comment: I'm guess he is.  There are a few different ways to do it - I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Eclipse, emacs, vi, notepad, etc. etc. :)  I assume he was asking 'are you letting Netbeans generate your code, or are you just using it as a fancy text editor?'

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In general you can do:

`JComboBox b = new JComboBox(new String[]{"String1","String2"});`

i.e. there is a contructor for initializing via arrays.
So you just have to override `toString()` in the objects contained in the array(if they are not of type String) .

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
private void combofill(){
       cbxplaces.removeAllItems();
       String[] place= {"Cont", "Cancel","TEST"};  
        DefaultComboBoxModel mod = new DefaultComboBoxModel(place);
           cbxplaces.setModel(mod);
    }
```

Comment: Try this method.