# Netbeans GUI Spinner - only allow it to go so high

Tags: java, swing

I want to restrict the spinner to go from 0 to 59. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same general process I described in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708289/add-the-contents-of-an-array-to-a-combo-box/4708323#4708323) to your [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708289/add-the-contents-of-an-array-to-a-combo-box) about combo boxes.  This will be a little more straight forward if your numbers are fixed:

1. Edit the model property for the spinner in the properties editor.
2. Select **Number** for the **Mode type**
3. Edit the fields as necessary

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Give your JSpinner a SpinnerNumberModel and construct the SpinnerNumberModel with parameters that fulfill your criteria.  e.g.,

```
// if the initial value will be 30, then this will set the spinner to 
// initialize at 30, have a range from 0 to 59, and a step size of 1
SpinnerNumberModel spinnerNumberModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(30, 0, 60, 1);
spinner.setModel(spinnerNumberModel);
```

Also, on a side note, I strongly urge you to learn to code Swing without the use of NetBeans-generated code as this will help you immensely in understanding what Swing is doing under the hood and how to best code in Swing with or without NetBeans generation.

Comment: Where does it go?  Hard to say.  Sorry to be blunt, but you're the one with all the program code, and who fully understands your program so only you know.

Answer (score 0):

A note.  Net beans will not let you edit this code yourself.  However if you go to the model and choose number you can specify the values that you want.